# Streaming .ts File Over UDP

Tags: udp, streaming, gstreamer, mpeg

I would like to stream .ts file over udp, for that i used the below pipeline.

But within a second it is reaching EOS

```
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=avm.ts ! queue ! tsparse ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.139 port=8080

Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:00.177011430
```

At Receiving end i am not able to receive whole data, only first few frame are coming because of instant exit at sending end.

While Streaming a .ts file which contains video & text data, at receiving end only getting, text data.

At sending end below debug messages came.

```
0:00:00.030345526  7863       0xd9df60 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3483:gst_base_src_start_complete:<filesrc0> pad not activated yet
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/MpegTsMux:mpegtsmux0.GstPad:sink_65: caps = "application/x-metadata\,\ standard\=\(string\)klv"
0:00:00.031289005  7863       0xd710f0 FIXME               basesink gstbasesink.c:3064:gst_base_sink_default_event:<udpsink0> stream-start event without group-id. Consider implementing group-id handling in the upstream elements
```

When i changed the pipeline and added identity, like,

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=vfpd.ts ! queue ! tsparse ! rtpmp2tpay ! identity silent=false ! udpsink -v host=192.168.1.139 port=8765
```

Then getting too many messages, like below,

```
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstIdentity:identity0: last-message = chain   ******* (identity0:sink) (1328 bytes, dts: none, pts:none, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: -1, flags: 00004000 tag-memory ) 0x7fcaf40abac0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstIdentity:identity0: last-message = chain   ******* (identity0:sink) (200 bytes, dts: none, pts:none, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: -1, flags: 00004000 tag-memory ) 0x7fcaf40abdf0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstIdentity:identity0: last-message = chain   ******* (identity0:sink) (1328 bytes, dts: none, pts:none, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: -1, flags: 00004000 tag-memory ) 0x7fcaf40db7f0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstIdentity:identity0: last-message = chain   ******* (identity0:sink) (1328 bytes, dts: none, pts:none, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: -1, flags: 00004000 tag-memory ) 0x7fcaf409d450
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstIdentity:identity0: last-message = chain   ******* (identity0:sink) (1328 bytes, dts: none, pts:none, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: -1, flags: 00004000 tag-memory ) 0x7fcaf4007460
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstIdentity:identity0: last-message = chain   ******* (identity0:sink) (200 bytes, dts: none, pts:none, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: -1, flags: 00004000 tag-memory ) 0x7fcaf40bfc10
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstIdentity:identity0: last-message = chain   ******* (identity0:sink) (1328 bytes, dts: none, pts:none, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: -1, flags: 00004000 tag-memory ) 0x7fcaf408f000
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstIdentity:identity0: last-message = chain   ******* (identity0:sink) (1328 bytes, dts: none, pts:none, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: -1, flags: 00004000 tag-memory ) 0x7fcaf409d560
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstIdentity:identity0: last-message = chain   ******* (identity0:sink) (952 bytes, dts: none, pts:none, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: -1, flags: 00004000 tag-memory ) 0x7fcaf408f330
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstIdentity:identity0: last-message = event   ******* (identity0:sink) E (type: eos (28174), ) 0x7fcaf4003400
```

So, as of my understanding, it is sending all the packets in a single instance, that means no flow control.

**The file is of 25 fps. And how can i stream the ts also in the same flow rate?**

What does that warning means? And how to resolve it?
How to resolve this issue? How can i slower the flow?

Comment: maybe play with sync parameter on sink..

Comment: doesn't give any improvement, nothing has changed

Comment: then check logs and find something interesting, put it here

Comment: check the question once please.

Comment: For transmission of ts file, i used demuxing and again muxing, it increases processing right. So, i would like to stream raw ts file without any muxing or decoding, can it possible if so, how?

Comment: well the pipe looks good, I am not sure why you recieve only few frames, I would put `! identity silent=false ! udpsink -v host=....` before udpsink and add the -v parameter somewhere and check how much packets is displayed .. if its just few like 5 or so its bad.. if its a lot than this approach may work.. please check with the identity and update this question with what you have found out :)

Comment: yeah. I updated the question, please check it once. I think all frames are streaming in a single instance, can i control the flow like 25fps or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used below pipeline, that solved my problem.

```
 GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=avm.ts ! queue ! tsdemux ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.139 port=8080
```

Comment: do not forget to accept it as correct answer (the grey tick below answer score)

Comment: You don't need the additional rtp encapsulation.  Remove the `rtpmp2pay` element  and you'll have mpegts over udp.  Works well.

Answer (score 4):

First - the pipe looks good to me..

From your update:

Well it looks like as I expected it goes in one burst (as you already stated), the problem is that in you original stream there are no timing informations inside frames (thats those none for dts, pts and duration).. there are two possible explanations - there is some problem in your .ts file.. or there is problem in gstreamer pipe..

Personaly I think that your .ts file is wrong..

To eliminate the first one I would suggest analyzing the .ts file with some mpeg analyzator..

You should check if the mpeg ts stream does contain proper [PCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream#PCR) values which is synchronization information for mpeg streams.

UPDATE:

Ok after little bit of hacking I found this solution, I hope it works on the reciever site, I tested just to stream it and it run for the length of the original [ts file](http://www.dododge.net/roku/ts-samples.html):

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=football.ts ! queue ! tsparse set-timestamps=true ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink -v host=192.168.1.139 port=8765
```

the `set-timestamps` is properly marking the buffers with time information..

Comment: if .ts file is wrong, then why it is playing very well by using playbin. Even when i use this pipeline, gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=vfpd.ts ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink.

Comment: I am sure that the ts file is well created, and it is decoding well

Comment: what happens if you put identity after that tsdemux? maybe there is bug in tsparse

Comment: when i set identity after tsdemux then packets are streaming as per the fps only. Not in a single instance

Comment: if i remove the tsparse on the first pipeline, then i am getting negotiation error, is there any way to replace the tsparse so that the pipeline will work?

Comment: @PrasanthKumarArisetti check the update of answer.. I found some argument for tsparse..

Comment: But I am using gstreamer-1.4.5, I don't find any property like set-timestamps for tsparse

Comment: ugh.. then you are out of luck.. try asking on [IRC](https://webchat.freenode.net/) at channel `#gstreamer` why its behaving like that and if there is another option..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112367/discussion-between-prasanth-kumar-arisetti-and-otopolsky).